# How to Sync variables in Unity3D Networking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

Hello Title was too general but I have several problems in my mind. I am new at UnityNetworking. I am watching youtube tutorial from quill18 and trying to implement on my project. So I know [SyncVar] values can only set and sync in server. But even I check isServer > hasAuthority > isLocalPlayer I cant be able to sync them properly. I can only be able to sync them only and only under isServer. Here is problem begins..

- So I have two public int variables with [SyncVar] and I am checking their values from Unity3D if they changed.
- If I change them under isServer if statement, they are changing both in Server and Client to 100 and 100.
- But after this If I change them in hasAuthority if statement they wont change same goes for isLocalPlayer...
- I tried changing them in a function before checking if isServer doesnt work.
- Even I try [Command] function, I know it runs in Server values still didn't change.

my code

```
private void Update()
{
    ServerUpdate();
    ClientUpdate();
} 

[SyncVar] public int syncIT_1;
[SyncVar] public int syncIT_2;

void WillItSyncNow()
{
    if (isServer)
    {
        syncIT_1 = 300;
        syncIT_2 = 300;
    }       
}

[Command]
void CmdSyncPlease()
{
    syncIT_1 = 400;
    syncIT_2 = 400;
}

void ServerUpdate()
{       
    if (isServer)
    {   
        syncIT_1 = 100;
        syncIT_2 = 100;

        if (hasAuthority)
        {
            syncIT_1 = 200;
            syncIT_2 = 200;

            if (isLocalPlayer == true)
            {
                WillItSyncNow();
                CmdSyncPlease();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Server Client Latest Values:

[image]

My Client Latest Values:

[image]

Comment: what does `ClientUpdate` do?

Comment: It is empty for now. But later I want to check ifServer then return and TurnTimer if equals 0 then EndTurn for client side..

Comment: The main problem here: I can Sync Values under first isServer control from ServerUpdate like syncIT_1 = 100; and then both clients and server got value of 100. But when I do like syncIT_1 = Random.Range(1, 100); both client and server get different values which I really want to know why. Isn't suppose to sync values from server side?.